# How do I count the number of records with no match on the right side of a Linq left join?

Tags: c#, linq, left-join

I am trying to analyse a phone bill, which comprises a load of mobile numbers and associated data. Each number either belongs to somebody in the company, or is unassigned.

I am using this query to match the mobile number to an employee record

```
var billInfo = from  row in csvTable.AsEnumerable()
               join d in employeeList 
               on row.Field<string>("Phone number") equals d.Mobile into t 
                from rt in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new
                     {
                       empNo = rt == null ? null : rt.EmpNo,
                       totalRows = csvTable.Rows.Count,
                       unassignedNumbers = t.Where(x => x.EmpNo == null).Count(),
                       name = row.Field<string>("User name"),
                       mobile = row.Field<string>("Phone number")
                      };
```

I want to get the number of unassigned numbers back in the unassignedNumbers field. (i.e. If there are 100 rows (one per phone number) in the csvTable datatable, and 70 have an employee record matching in employeeList, I want to return 30 as the value - the number of rows with no matching employee).

The following line:

```
unassignedNumbers = t.Where(x => x.EmpNo == null).Count,
```

is where the problem is. It always evaluates to zero, rather than the number of rows with an "empty" employee number (empNo).

Comment: @Alexey's suggestion has removed the error, but I'm now getting 0 back as a result of the query. How can I get a count of the rows with an empty empNo on the fly?

Comment: @Sobitan `rt` is just one item from `t` or `null` if there where no matching items.

Comment: ...alright then how about using maths....i.e totalRows - (t.Where(x => x.EmpNo != null).Count()) ......subtracting the gotten record from the total count......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is giving you at least one item for each item in your `csvTable`.  The data you want for `unassignedNumbers` would be exactly one value for the entire data set.  So you'd have to do a completely separate query to do that and then just assign that value directly into the results of your query if desired.

```
int allUnassignedNumbers = 
    (from  row in csvTable.AsEnumerable()
    join d in employeeList 
    on row.Field<string>("Phone number") equals d.Mobile into t 
    from rt in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where rt == null
    select 1).Count();

var billInfo = 
    from  row in csvTable.AsEnumerable()
    join d in employeeList 
    on row.Field<string>("Phone number") equals d.Mobile into t 
    from rt in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        empNo = rt == null ? null : rt.EmpNo,
        totalRows = csvTable.Rows.Count,
        unassignedNumbers = allUnassignedNumbers,
        name = row.Field<string>("User name"),
        mobile = row.Field<string>("Phone number")
    };
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `Count()`, not `Count`. The latter is an `ICollection<T>` property, while you're dealing with an `IEnumerable<T>`.

As for the logic of your query, you are running `t.Where()` on `t`, which is an inner join. Try

```
var billInfo = (from  row in csvTable.AsEnumerable()
           join d in employeeList 
           on row.Field<string>("Phone number") equals d.Mobile into t 
           from rt in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
           where rt == null
           select row.Field<string>("Phone number")).Count();
```